# How to get decent ocean meeting horizon for camera in motion at z+3000m?

Tags: ocean-simulation, skybox

working on making an animation involving a (steampunk-ish) airship in flight over the ocean, and wondering if anyone has tips for a water plane at sea-level that doesn't obviously truncate before the horizon / leave a big visible gap of gray where the "bottom" of the sky texture is visible? The ship will be flying at about 3000m, and the camera will be moving about so forced perspective tricks aren't likely to be helpful.

Comment: What object is your "sky texture" on? Can't you put it on a vertical plane which ends below the z position of the ocean object?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JohnEason - Good point of clarification. I currently have setup the environment texture using a [Sky Texture Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/sky.html) synced with a realistic [Sun Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/lighting/sun_position.html).

Comment: @elfprince13 I think we'd need an image of what you have currently in that case. The Sky environment texture shouldn't show any "big visible gap of gray". Have you tried playing with the Altitude setting? - It's described under the Input [Properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/sky.html#properties) in the Blender manual.

Comment: @JohnEason - Yeah, I have the sky texture altitude set to 3000m, the foreground objects at 0m (± a few meters on either side), and the ocean at -3000m. A screenshot of the render preview in current configuration is here: https://imgur.com/a/zjaBxlg 

I got rid of the big visible gap by adjusting the clipping distance for the camera, but my ocean plane currently has to be 100000m in size, which feels kind of crazy (assuming replacing it with a circle will get rid of that one visible corner).

Comment: You should edit your question and directly add that comment into your question along with your image. It will then be resubmitted and maybe someone else will be able to give you an answer.